# How can I filter a multidimensional array and count the filtered values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array coming from a mysql database. So it is structured this way (just the first two entry):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_cre] => CD000000001
            [0] => CD000000001
            [id_az] => AZ000000001
            [1] => AZ000000001
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_cre] => CD000000002
            [0] => CD000000002
            [id_az] => 
            [1] => 
        )
)
```

I would like to count how many entries in the array have `[id_az] =>''`.

If I do:

```
count($creds)
```

I get `2` (the number of items in the array).

I'd prefer to reuse this array (the query runs already for another report),  instead of doing a new query with the WHERE clause to subselect `WHERE id_az = ''`.

Any hint(s)?

Comment: did you a foreach loop?

Comment: No, I won't do a foreach if it is not necessary. If I check that no elements of the array have the id_az key-value pair empty I won't run the foreach

Comment: that doesn't make any sense at all. Just make the check in the foreach loop and skip elements with an empty "id_az" with continue

Comment: this is not the place to discuss my software architecture but trust me if I say that this solution is way too fast. I have 1000 entries in the array and should execute code inside the foreach only for one or two and only in case of problems with the data (where I miss id_az). But most of the times I won't execute it at all. So I should run a foreach on 1000 items and skip 998 or 1000 of them??? in that case I'd go for a second query don't you agree?

Comment: well, you have to loop over all of them anyway - array_* has to iterate, foreach as to iterate - someone has to go over your array and check the values. array_* function are usually slower than a foreach. But the array will get iterated, one way or another. the only thing that's different, is that you'll need the memory for the data created from the array_column - but since you're "only" handling a thousand entries, it doesn't really matter that much anyway. Sorry for trying to help you to reach an optimal implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just get the column `id_az` with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the array then, e.g.

```
echo count(array_column($creds, "id_az"));
```

Comment: didn't know about array_column! thanks for the hint. But I'd like to count if `id_az=''` the key is there anyway!

Comment: @LelioFaieta Then just apply an `array_filter()` call to filter all values out, which aren't empty, e.g. `echo count(array_filter(array_column($creds, "id_az"), "empty"));`

Comment: php tells me that function 'empty' not found or invalid function name. I guess I have to go for a match between count($creds) that count all the entries in the array and count(array_filter(array_column($creds, "id_az"), strlen)); that removes all NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings but leaves 0 (zero) values and if the two values are different I will have some entries with id_az=''

Comment: array_column is PHP >= v5.5

Comment: @LelioFaieta Ah, forgot, you can't pass empty just as callback, you have to write it in an anonymous function .e.g. `count(array_filter(array_column($arr, "id_az"), function($v){return empty($v);}));`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a good old foreach loop?

```
$count = 0;
foreach($data as $row)
{
  $count += empty($row['id_az']) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

or alternativly an array_map with a anonymous function

```
$count = 0;
array_map(function($row) use (&$count) { $count += empty($row['id_az']) ? 0 : 1; }, $data);
```

But this is PHP >5.3. Callbacks won't work, since you won't have access to a variable to store your count in.

Comment: I am using this to check if the foreach (with a lot of code inside) must be run. If no array entries satisfy this I won't do It!

Comment: foreach is a lot faster than array_map or any of the array_ fuctions, if that is a concern for you.

Comment: the foreach have too much code inside and I want to run it only if it is necessary (I am checking if data are consistent). If they are not then run the foreach and do a lot of things to validate the data

Comment: foreach($data as $row) { if(empty($row['id_az']) { continue; } /* rest of your code */ } - the amount of code inside a foreach loop has no real impact on runtime or performance - afaik.